# Issues When Rescuing ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm attempting to build a table which will act as a queue of batched syncs to a third party service.

The following method should speak for itself; but to be clear, its intention is to add a new updatable object (a polymorphic relationship) with `status: :queued` to the `delayed_syncs` table.

There is a uniqueness constraint on the polymorphic relationship + `status` (`updatable_id`, `updatable_type`, `status`) which should cause updatable objects already in the queue with the `:queued status` to fail here and fall into the rescue block.

The issue I am seeing is that whenever the `SELECT` generated by `find_by` is fired, this entire method fails with a:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

error.

Information I've found around this suggests a `ROLLBACK` or `RELEASE SAVEPOINT` after the failed `INSERT`, but I'm not sure how I would accomplish that here.

The aforementioned method:

```
def self.enqueue(updatable:, action:)
  DelayedSync.create(updatable: updatable, status: :queued, action: action)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  queued_update = DelayedSync.find_by(updatable: updatable, status: :queued, action: :sync_update)
  if action == :sync_delete && queued_update.present?
    queued_update.sync_delete!
  else
    Rails.logger.debug "#{updatable.class.name} #{updatable.id} already queued for sync, skipping."
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging, I uncovered the problem was due to how I was invoking this method from an `after_save` callback. Rails invokes `after_save` and `after_destroy` callbacks **before** the transaction has been closed. Rescuing the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error invoked from this callback and attempting to execute more queries is impossible with Postgres, since it invalidates the entire transaction. My solution was to transition to the `after_commit` callback which provides the same control as `after_save` and `after_destroy` with the `on: [:create, :destroy]` parameter, with the benefit of being executed **after** the transaction (invalid or not) has closed.

This blog post is a bit dated, but the information near the bottom was immensely helpful and still holds true: http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rely on exception handling for logic, you can use `ActiveRecord` transactions to ensure all-or-nothing updates.

Like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  DelayedSync.create!(updatable: updatable, status: :queued, action: action)
end
```

You can still safely utilize `rescue` to handle logging cleanup.

Docs that have much more detail about this can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).